# Way to create numpy array to contain only unique elements for lists within it

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array A which looks like this:

```
array([list(['nan', 'nan']),
       list(['nan', 'nan', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'nan', 'nan']),
       list(['red', 'red']), ...,
       list(['nan', 'festival'])], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert this to an array in which each list contains only unique elements. For example, I  want the above array to get converted to:

```
['nan'],['nan','apple','banana'],['red'],...,['nan','festival']
```

I have tried doing this:

```
output = []
for i in A:
    output.append(np.unique(i))
output
```

The output which I get doing this is not desired and currently looks like this:

```
[array(['nan'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['nan'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['nan'], dtype='<U3'),....]
```

What can be done?

Comment: This code produse `[array(['nan'], dtype='<U3'), array(['apple', 'banana', 'nan'], dtype='<U6'), array(['red'], dtype='<U3'), array([Ellipsis], dtype=object), array(['festival', 'nan'], dtype='<U8')]` for me.

Comment: Yes it does, but can we remove the [array([..],dtype='<U3'] part and only have ```['nan'],['nan','apple','banana'],['red'],...,['nan','festival']```

Comment: Use  list instead of an array, and `set` instead of `unique`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr=np.array([list(['nan', 'nan']),
       list(['nan', 'nan', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'nan', 'nan']),
       list(['red', 'red']), ...,
       list(['nan', 'festival'])], dtype=object)
```

try via list comprehension:

```
out=[np.unique(x).tolist() for x in arr]
```

**OR**

```
out=[list(np.unique(x)) for x in arr]
```

output of `out`:

```
[['nan'], ['apple', 'banana', 'nan'], ['red'], [Ellipsis], ['festival', 'nan']]
```

Comment: This is exactly the output I was getting. What I am looking for is getting an output that contains only the unique values and not additional information such as dtype.

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for, `['nan','apple','banana']` should remain in the same list.

Comment: @user31934 Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thnx @Guy for noticing **:)**

Comment: `[ list(set(x)) for x in ...]` should be faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks sir for suggestion but sir it will throw an error `TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable`

Comment: Your copy-n-paste included `...`!

Comment: ohh sorry sir for my stupidness....you are Right Sir....thanks again sir **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Simple non-numpy answer

```
In [239]: alist =[list(['nan', 'nan']),
     ...:        list(['nan', 'nan', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'nan', 'nan']),
     ...:        list(['red', 'red']),
     ...:        list(['nan', 'festival'])]
In [240]: alist
Out[240]: 
[['nan', 'nan'],
 ['nan', 'nan', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'nan', 'nan'],
 ['red', 'red'],
 ['nan', 'festival']]
In [241]: [list(set(i)) for i in alist]
Out[241]: [['nan'], ['banana', 'apple', 'nan'], ['red'], ['festival', 'nan']]
```

`numpy` will be slower.

There shouldn't have been any problem with your iteration:

```
In [245]: output = []
     ...: for i in np.array(alist,object):
     ...:     output.append(np.unique(i))
     ...: output
Out[245]: 
[array(['nan'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['apple', 'banana', 'nan'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['red'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['festival', 'nan'], dtype='<U8')]
```

`np.unique` is a `numpy` function, so returns an array, not a list.  For simple case like this, with lists of strings, `set` works and is much faster.